# How to fetch images from slow API in React.js and Typescript and axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I want to fetch an **image url** to use as the value for the **src tag**

```
            <img
              src={getAircraftImage(foundFlight.aircraft.reg)}
              alt="Aircraft"
              className="rounded-md w-24 h-12"
            />
```

```
function getAircraftImage(reg: string | undefined): string {
  let imageUrl;
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://aerodatabox.p.rapidapi.com/aircrafts/reg/${reg}/image/beta`,
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "6445ce28c1msh4b2afb9dc1a38bbp17a68bjsn97511bcb4bbf",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "aerodatabox.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  axios
    .request(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      imageUrl = response.data.url;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

  return imageUrl;
}
```

**Problem** The Api is not that fast. When i load the image only the alt tag is shown. I have seen in multiple websites a way to show a fallback image as the request is made then show the correct image after but i dont know how to implement it. How do i accomplish that?

Comment: Just use hooks. `useEffect` to properly execute the request, `useState` to store the result and render conditionally. You may want to use this hook combination in any scenario where you need to do a request to an external API.

Comment: @LukaCerrutti an example in code if you don`t mind?

Comment: Added an example in a new answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments: Just use hooks. `useEffect` to properly execute the request, `useState` to store the result and render conditionally. You may want to use this hook combination in any scenario where you need to do a request to an external API. As a code example, for a simple component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const MyComponent = () => {
  // create state of loading, but also state for data
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  // useEffect to execute request
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        // gets response and saves data into 'data' state
        const {data: response} = await axios.get('/stuff/to/fetch');
        setData(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // conditional rendering if already loaded
  return (
    <div>
    {loading && <div>Loading</div>}
    {!loading && (
      <div>
        <h2>Doing stuff with data</h2>
        {data.map(item => (<span>{item.name}</span>))}
      </div>
    )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Source: https://dev.to/darkmavis1980/fetching-data-with-react-hooks-and-axios-114h